# Scala: pattern matching on a type with a given "path"?

Tags: scala, types, pattern-matching, classpath

Lets say I have:

```
object myObject{
  class myClass1(){
      class myClass11(){
        class myClass111
      }
      class myClass12(){
        class myClass121
      }
    }
}

class myClass{
  class myClass2(){
      object myObj21
      object myObj22
   }
}
```

I want to pattern match on the types and objects introduced above and get instances of:

1. `myClass1` only (nested type inside an object)
2. `myClass11` and `myClass12` (doubly nested types inside `aObject/aClass`)
3. `myClass2` only (nested type inside a class)
4. `myObj21` , `myObj22` only. (doubly nested types inside `aClass/aClass`)
5. `myClass111`, `myClass121`. ( nested types in different branches but the same nest level and same "root")

ie. different variations of object/class and same level types or same sublevel types.

Can I do this with a type "regex" equivalent instead of spelling the type paths explicitly?

Comment: @negative votes: I fail to understand how this question is too broad. perhaps you could read the question?

Comment: I know. I only mentioned regex to illustrate what I was trying to do! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no nice way to do this. Pattern matching on nested types at all is iffy, let alone complex matches about them.

You might be able to write some custom unapply to do this kind of stuff using reflection, or perhaps even a macro. But thinking about that rabbit hole makes me wonder why this is necessary in the first place. Maybe you could add some traits that represent what actual behavior you care about, and pattern match on those?